# Método imageView.getDrawable() lança NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, imageview

Queria pegar a drawable da ImageView e converte-la para um bitmap. O método de conversão eu já possuo e está funcionando bem porem, quando solicito a execução, ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

## Erro Apresentado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando pego a imagem direto da pasta Drawable do projeto funciona, o erro só ocorre quando tento pegar a imagem da ImageView.

## Activity_main:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Bitmap bitmap; //vai guardar a imagem da ImageView
    private ImageView image; //Possui a Imagem que quero converter

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    }

    public void converte(View v){
        bitmap = drawableToBitmap(image.getDrawable());
    }

    public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
           BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
            if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
                return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            }
        }
        if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {//O ERRO OCORRE AQUI. . .
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } else {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é a linha 83 da MainActivity?

Comment: É o segundo if do método drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable). 
Está comentado lá.

Comment: Desculpe, não tinha visto. Em que momento vc chama o método converte(View v), o que vc está passando nesse parâmetro?

Comment: Chamo quando clico no button apresentado no layout

Comment: Como você está a atribuir a imagem à ImageView?

Comment: Faço isso pelo layout mesmo, clico na imagem /  background e seleciono a imagem desejada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O método `image.getDrawable()` está a retornar `null`, daí o `NullPointerException`

Você tem de atribuir a imagem à *ImageView* através do atributo `android:src` e não do atributo `android:background`.